# How can I attach some data to an image in a Google Docs Add-on script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs-api

My Google docs add-on takes some text and converts it to an image. I store the original text in the LINK_URL attribute. But this attribute can be lost by certain operations and it is also editable by the user.

Is there any way I can associate some data with an InlineImage in a Google Docs document? Is there any way to identify an image as one that my script created?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [named ranges](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/named-range) to associate a name or generate a unique ID for a section of a document. You could then use the names or IDs as keys in a datastore (document properties, etc) to retrieve related metadata.